# Error 0xc000007b after installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit with UEFI enabled (since Windows came preinstalled) and I want to keep Windows. I created a partition, installed Ubuntu successfully and then I repaired grub2 with Boot-Repair. I get the black on gray dialog that displays the Windows and Ubuntu entries but when I select Ubuntu I get an error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi  

  Status: 0xc0000007b  

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required   
        file is missing or contains errors.
```

saying that the file is corrupt or doesn't exist. Is there any way to fix this? I tried it with and without `secure boot` enabled.

Edit: the notebook is a sony vaio s if it helps.

Comment: Try to reinstall GRUB from your Live Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

UEFI is known to cause problems with Ubuntu. I have yet to find a case where a UEFI installation initially works. The best fix for this is `boot-repair`. Here's what you can do to fix your problem:

1. Start  up your Live CD
2. Open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair`
4. Run `sudo boot-repair`
5. Choose the Recommended Repair
6. Follow the instructions you are given, then reboot once finished
7. Profit!

Comment: I already tried that, I said so in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but try preparing a USB flash drive with the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You should be able to boot to rEFInd, which should give options for both Windows and Linux -- probably at least two for Linux. Select a Linux option with the string `vmlinuz` in the description. If this boots Linux, install the Debian package version of rEFInd, which will replace GRUB as your boot manager. If rEFInd fails, post details, including any error messages you see.

Another point: I doubt if it's related to your problem, but a common issue with Windows 8/Linux dual-boot setups is the new Windows "fast startup" feature. This feature turns shutdown operations into suspend-to-disk operations, which has the undesirable effect of not properly unmounting filesystems. This in turn results in filesystem damage because the two OSes don't share the same view of the disk. Thus, it's ***imperative*** that you disable this feature, as described [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) (among other places).

Answer (score 0):

**Try 32 bit version of EFI.**

The windows you are using is 32 bit, so mbr is writed in 32 bit manner. You must use 32bit version of loader which will load you 64bit host OS